# No one has ever seen God or can see God, what were the colors John used to describe Him in Revelation 4:1-5?

Tags: nature-of-god, revelation

The throne room of God is described in Revelation Chapter 4:1-5 in detail.

> After these things I looked, and behold, a door standing open in heaven. And the first voice which I heard was like a trumpet speaking with me, saying, “Come up here, and I will show you things which must take place after this.”
> 2 Immediately I was in the Spirit; and behold, a throne set in heaven, and One sat on the throne. 3 And He who sat there was like a jasper and a sardius stone in appearance; and there was a rainbow around the throne, in appearance like an emerald. 4 Around the throne were twenty-four thrones, and on the thrones I saw twenty-four elders sitting, clothed in white robes; and they had crowns of gold on their heads. 5 And from the throne proceeded lightnings, thunderings, and voices. Seven lamps of fire were burning before the throne, which are the seven Spirits of God. Revelation 4:1-5

I did a research of what this throne room looks like and managed to find this from the internet.

> [image]

Given that the picture above has attempted to factor in the verses that say God dwells in a light that cannot be approached.

**1st Timothy 6:16**

> who alone is immortal and who lives in unapproachable light, whom no one has seen or can see. To him be honor and might forever. Amen.

Paul who was also inspired by Jesus wrote a letter to Timothy and describes God as dwelling in a light that cannot be approached and mentions two important facts about God.

> No one has ever seen God, not even Jesus or the Spirit. This is similar to the knowledge about The Return of the Son of Man when Jesus disqualifies himself and the angels from knowing about his second coming.

> No one can see God. This means not even John saw God in the vision in Revelation.

So what is the Jasper and sardius stone color description John used to describe God with?

Comment: they are stones? basic search results: [jasper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasper) and [carnelian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnelian)

Comment: yes they are stones with certain colors

Comment: https://www.minerals.net/gemstone/jasper_gemstone.aspx

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnelian_(color)

Comment: @Lesley, but Paul literally said no one has ever or can see God.

Comment: @DongLi that isn't the question you posted, and there are several questions around this scripture no one has ever or can see God

Comment: This is true - but Paul was taken up in the spirit and was given a vision.  Everything in Revelation is to be discerned spiritually.

Comment: @depperm, if there is a an overwhelming light source then you cannot see what is at the center of that light because that's God Himself. Unless John saw God and used these colors to describe him

Comment: @Lesley, the picture I attached has the colors of both stones but they are outside the light radiated by God. They also got the four living creatures wrong, each of those creatures sorrounding the throne of  each of the four sides of the throne not lined up in the same front side of the throne

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the representation provided is wholly erroneous.

Comment: Visons and pictures are not the reality - they simply try to describe what is indescribable. Revelation 4:1-5 is full of symbolism.

Comment: We will never understand God unless through the lamb. It's only Jesus who made him known to us and his eternal good will. I now believe God created all the billions of stars and planets in the universe. How can man deny this truth?

Comment: In Genesis when God says let there be light, he is commanding his presence at a certain point in a dark universe with literally nothing at all. Then he shares his life with us and creates us out of the dust of the earth.

Comment: "If I have told you earthly things, and ye believe not, how shall ye believe, if I tell you of heavenly things? - John 3:12".  Human language and imagination fail to fully capture and convey God.  God condescends to speak to us through concepts we can grasp and He condescended to take on human flesh and come to us.  Still we struggle to understand, What are streets of gold?

Comment: @MikeBorden, precisely the son of man told us of earthly things and we believed him not. What if he told us of heavenly things? Our understanding falls short just like the Jews thought the Messiah was going to be an early king who was going to save the Hebrews from Roman rule but he was going to be far bigger than that, The dead shall hear the voice of the Son of Man and they shall be raised with new bodies. This is a repetition of how he called life out of dust in the beginning so in the end he calls life out of dust where the dead are buried.

Answer (score 3):

All the colours of the rainbow are mentioned in the book of the Revelation, yet the rainbow above the throne of God is said to be emerald! I didn't notice that in the Internet computer graphic you showed. Yes, there's lots of emerald colour above the throne, but in no way looking like a rainbow. Nobody on earth is going to do justice to any artistic impression of the scenes in heaven.

In particular, the jasper and the sardius are asked about - their colour. Let me quote from this 618-page book on the whole of the Revelation, this bit being a comment on ch. 21 vs. 12 which also mentions the jasper:

> 'Her light was like unto a stone most precious, even like **a jasper
> stone, clear as crystal**.' In the likeness of the glory of Almighty
> God upon the throne, ch. 4, it was observed that ***he who sat upon
> the throne was like a jasper and a sardius stone***. Likewise before
> the throne there appeared a sea of glass, clear as crystal. Shining
> out of the depths of the jasper stone, as of a flawless diamond,
> flashes of profound and glorious light appeared. This was a radiance
> from which all must perforce turn their eyes, even as the living
> creatures in the midst of the throne covered their faces with their
> wing... They could not look upon him, the light was unbearable,
> unapproachable..." *The Revelation of Jesus Christ*, p. 594, John
> Metcalfe

The author adds that sardius was ruby or garnet. "**Amidst the clear, brilliant purity of the jasper came flashes of deep red**, the colour of wrath." (*Ibid*. p. 9)  He also says that this blaze of inconceivable light is not an architectural blueprint:

> "It is this that is to be interpreted, not some imagined carnal
> literalism. What is being conveyed transcends all human thought,
> imagination, conception, idealism, comprehension, or capacity. ...that
> such a vision should be given at all, ought to silence all mortal
> flesh, draw all spiritual creation, and be received with that awesome
> divinity and transcendent wonder with which it overwhelmed the Seer.
> There is no room here for the mind of man, or for rational thought, in
> a revelation of dimensions passing all understanding. Such grace in
> sending the vision leaves the true worshippers prostrate in reverence.
>
> At once allegorical, metaphorical, figurative, visionary; all of this.
> Yet, for it all, the revelation is as near to hinting of the reality
> as present words can remotely express." (*Ibid.* p. 593)

Comment: What are your thoughts on the truth Paul wrote to Saint Timothy regarding the unapproachable light where God dwells in?

Comment: @Dong Li  Comments are not to extend the question; you would need to ask a new question on that. I would gladly answer that, because the comment box would not be big enough to do justice to such an answer.